# Is it possible to run TrueCrypt bootloader on a Sony Vaio S?

Tags: truecrypt, bootloader, sony-vaio

We run TrueCrypt bootloader on Sony Vaio E series laptops and it runs fine requiring users to enter a password before the machine will load the OS.

However, on the Sony S series laptops, TrueCrupt installs, goes to reboot but then never loads the bootloader leaving the laptop doing nothing and unusable.

Has anyone come across this or a solution?

Comment: Does that Sony come with any factory encryption protection, hard drive, TPM etc, maybe there is a conflict

Comment: Check the bios for something like virus protection, boot protection, mbr protection or something similar. It prevents the MBR from being modified, protecting against rootkits, but makes system installation, or in this case, TC installation, impossible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue was due to a combination of version problems. Using a newer Bios with TrueCrypt 7.0a (not 7.0) solves the problem and allows full drive encryption.